# First element of array not showing

Tags: c++, vector

I was coding a function that squares every number and then sort the array in ascending order 
But When I ran my code it is not showing the first element of the array  
i.e. if the array is [1 2 3 4 5]

It is showing only [ 4 9 16 25 ]
Code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

void sortedSquaredArray(vector<int> &v){

    vector<int> ans;

    int leftPtr = 0;
    int rightPtr = v.size()-1;
    while(leftPtr < rightPtr){
        if(abs(v[leftPtr]) < abs(v[rightPtr])){
            ans.push_back(v[rightPtr] * v[rightPtr]);
            rightPtr--;
        }
        else{
            ans.push_back(v[leftPtr] * v[leftPtr]);
            leftPtr++;
        }
    }

    reverse(ans.begin(),ans.end());

    cout<<"Sorted Squared Array: [ ";
    for(int i=0; i<ans.size(); i++){
        cout<<ans[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<"]"<<endl;

}

int main(){

    // ? Given an integer array 'a' sorted in non-decreasing order, return an array of squares of each number sorted in non-decreasing order

    int n; cin>>n;

    vector<int> v;

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        int ele; cin>>ele;
        v.push_back(ele);
    }

    sortedSquaredArray(v);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: when the input has odd number of elements the last element is when `leftptr == rightptr`, but you do not handle that element

Comment: 4 9 16 25 are all squares of 2,3,4 and 5

Comment: well ok then you should provide the example input in the question

Comment: I am sorry I accidentally typed outputs in place of inputs

Comment: a debugger helps to spot such issues. It lets you step through your code line by line and you can see where something unexpected happens

Comment: You are just missing `while(leftPtr <= rightPtr)` , but I agree, you would have noticed with a simple debugger or by printing each state

Comment: can you recommend any debugger in vs code

Comment: the [native one](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cpp-debug) (?)

Comment: to gain time, whenever u need user input, you can test with fixed objects like `vector<int> v= {7,8,-1,1,2,3,4,5};`

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but `sortSquaredArray` is used in a rather peculiar way: the call from `main` creates an array and passes it to the function, then doesn't use the result. In general, functions like `sortSquaredArray` should do one thing, in this case, sort the array. Let `main` (or some other caller in a more complex program) display the result, or do whatever else is appropriate.

Comment: Also, `sortSquaredArray` stores the values largest first, then reverses them. It should store them smallest first, and not go through the data again to fix the order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an equals sign in your "while" inside sortedSquaredArray function. It should look like this: `while(leftPtr <= rightPtr)`.